# Http 503 — Service Unavailable error after successful craft 4 installation. Can't even load a hi.txt file in web root

Tags: error, installation

After successfully getting my DB setup and installing Craft through the command line, I'm getting a persistent 503 error on even a simple hi.txt file

https://saltandpepper.recipes/hi.txt

On the admin page it loads the raw html, but none of the dependent CSS or javascript seems to be loading. https://saltandpepper.recipes/admin/install I'v seen other 503 error issues reported here, but none that seem to apply to my situation. I don't know what could be going wrong

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your config/db.php has the wrong environment variables.

Craft 4 started prefixing all env vars with `CRAFT_`.